# What is the part of X11 in X11VNC?

Tags: x11, vnc, vnc-server

I understand that RFB protocol is used to remote display.  X11VNC uses the RFB protocol so that any VNC viewer (RFB-based) can view the display.

### Question:

1. Let's assume I have a frame buffer /dev/fb0 for example. I just can write and run the application that reads from framebuffer based on RFB Protocol.  In this case, what does X11VNC differs from it.
2. Also, X11VNC itself provides the option to use raw frame buffer. What is the difference between using/not using this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x11vnc uses X11 requests to get your screen updates - via Composite/Damage extensions when available or just by doing GetImage requests at time interval and diffing it with local copy. You want to know not only current image of the screen at any point of time but also *when* it was changed and *what area* was affected. Also with x11vnc you can track individual window instead of whole screen - there is fair number of x11 features in addition to just rfb server.

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks Andrey. Using X11vnc should give then better implementation of finding diff than if i happen to write myself.  RFB (reading from Spec) as such does not specify how to take a diff from frame buffer, right?.

Comment: rfb streams rectangles (possibly compressed) with new content of what's on screen after update. E.i when you type character in the terminal rfb will send small rectangle like "hey vnc client, screen at location [100, 100, 16x16] is now this bitmap". The client usually replies "oh, nice, please send me next update as soon as something changed"

Comment: so, in the case of x11vnc + rfb,  rfb will get the help from x11 to get the latest update and rfb streams ( as you said compressed) and send back to client. rfb itself will not determine what changes appeared on screen. is that correct?

Comment: x11vnc acts as a rfb server and client to X11 server, there is no independent "rfb" srvice here, it's just a name for protocol. x11vnc  is just a program that happens to talk both protocols (X11 and rfb)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey.